# Multiple fields required if Dropdown is selected to Yes

Tags: 2013, list, validation

I have a multichoice dropdown that has the response of Yes or No. If the response is set to yes, then I need it to make other fields required. After doing some research, I found a way blog that explains how to make a single field required if it is set to yes.

The problem is, I need multiple and after a few hours of research and trying this or that, I am unable to figure it out. Below is what I have for one field. Can someone show me how to do it for multiple?

```
=IF([Dropdown]="Yes",IF([Field1]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Resources:

- http://summit7systems.com/how-to-conditionally-require-data-in-sharepoint-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AND() function with the code snippet that's been provided.

`=AND((=IF([Dropdown]="Yes",IF([Field1]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)),(IF([Dropdown]="Yes",IF([Field2]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)),(=IF([Dropdown]="Yes",IF([Field3]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)))`

Comment: I tried this and I get this error "The formula cannot refer to another column.". I am assuming you mean go into the settings for each column and add that line to the Column Validation?

Comment: Ah, I was mentally going through the process and didn't test it; I was thinking of the wrong area.  You could try using the AND() function.  AND(<if for field1>,<if for field2>, etc.).

[This link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-78956048-53c7-484a-ab0b-6e70d7f03400) says it only applies to 2007 and earlier, but I know it works in 2010 as well, so I would guess it works in 2013.

Comment: I actually got it after a while longer, just now got a chance to test it out. After I realized Excel uses the same type of functions, I looked it up that way and found my answer. Will post an answer, but it looks like your way may be a little cleaner so I am curious what you come up with.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

After realizing that SharePoint uses about the same type of functions as Excel, I went at it that method and was able to use Excel for much easier testing. Here is my solution:

```
=IF([Dropdown]="Yes",IF([Field1]<>"",IF([Field2]<>"",IF([Field3]<>"",IF([Field4]<>"",IF([Field5]<>"",IF([Field6]<>"",IF(Field7]<>"",TRUE,FALSE))))))))
```

I learned that you can nest this all the way up to 64 IF statements.